# Increment character value of a string

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

Here is a small function, was testing something so wrote it. Here i tried to increment a character value of the string literal when i tried doing so i got a segmentation fault. Can you please tell what i am doing wrong here

```
#include <stdio.h>
int input_string(char *str)
{
  printf("%s\n", str);
  printf("%c\n", *str);
  printf("%c\n", (*str)++); // I get a segmentation fault here, cant i increment the value like this ?
}
void main()
{
  char *str = "andrew";
  input_string(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this `char *str = "andrew";` does is create a pointer to a string that MAY be located on .text (where the executable code resides) and trying to modify it is undefined behavior.

Change it for this:

```
char str[] = "andrew";
```

It will make a copy of the string in a stack allocated buffer that you can safely modify.

Comment: So any such initialization like char *ptr = "Stack" to a char ptr declaration, will be like a const char *ptr = "stack";

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact when you do something like that, you should declare it as `const` to prevent these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
char *str = "andrew";
```

means what str points to a constant string literal. You will get undefined behavior if you try to change it.

If you want to perform string manipulation, define a character array.